# Google map on load showing error

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I am using Google map one of my site. To show address and map I have used [gmap3 plugin](http://gmap3.net). It was working fine 2 days back. But it is showing error today when the map is loading like this

```
NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4sbbsr&7sUS&9sen-US&callback=_xdc_._2cs449&token=63445
```

Can someone kindly tell me whats the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Oh...I got the solution. I was trying to link googlemap by downloading the googlemap from the server and I was linking the file with my app. Instead of that I had to link directly to the google server. I just linked to the google map api directly and it worked finally..